# Populate flatlist from api restful

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to get values from my api restful and load on my flatlist. But It's not working.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  FlatList,
  Row
} from 'react-native';

export default function HomeScreen() {

  const highScores = fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      console.log(responseJson.movies);
      return responseJson.movies;

    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
      alert(error);
    });

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>

      <ScrollView
        style={styles.container}
        contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}>

        <View>
          <FlatList
            data={highScores}
            renderItem={
              ({ item, index }) =>
                <Row highScore={item} index={index} key={index} />
            }
          />
        </View>

        );
    }
```

Take a look, I'm accessing https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json to get his data after I'll load into highScores and finally populate my FlatList. But it's not working... Somebody may help me fixing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saving the high scores too late, after the render in fact. Try state and effect hooks to save the high scores and trigger a rerender.

```
function App() {
  const [highScores, setHighScores] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        console.log(responseJson.movies);
        // return responseJson.movies;
        setHighScores(responseJson.movies);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
        alert(error);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {highScores.map(({ title, releaseYear }, index) => (
        <div index={index} key={index}>
          {title}: {releaseYear}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit determined-diffie-1s2z0]

Comment: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: useState.

Comment: `import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";` but I guess it isn't clear what version of react/react-native you're using, hooks were introduced in React 16.8.